# Customize Lock Screen to show Sleep button or allow BTT shortcuts to work in Lock Screen

Tags: macos, keyboard, sleep-wake, bettertouchtool

Use case: I am logged in, at one point I locked the machine, and the Lock Screen is being displayed, prompting for a password.

MacOS catalina - 10.15.3

- I am looking for a way to Sleep the machine without having to put the password to unlock. Via shortcut while in the Lock Screen, or via adding a button/menu item in the Lock Screen.

I couldn't find any way to customize the lock screen in MacOS.

- I tried setting up shortcuts with Better touch tool - the shortcuts (e.g. Ctrl+Cmd+Options+) work fine while the machine is unlocked, but do not work in the lock screen.
- I also tried setting up trackpad shortcuts which don’t work on lock screen
- Finally I also tried creating a MacOS "normal" shortcut (Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcut > All Apps, menu item = "Sleep"), which also works fine while logged in + unlocked but does not work in the lock screen

Why I want this: I setup the machine to not sleep while AC power is ON, this is my preferred setting while in the office. On occasion, say at the end of the day, I still want the machine to enter sleep mode. Often, I find the machine in Lock Screen mode.

Comment: How is this different than never locking / sleeping and having a screen saver without a password?

Comment: @Mike I do use a locking policy, I just want to avoid sleep, when the AC power is connected. Typical usecase: office use, the machine connected to servers, apps running etc, I'd rather the machine doesn't sleep. Locking is needed as I'm in an office environment. Occasionally though I want to trigger sleep b/c I'm taking the laptop back home, or going for an extended period of time etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Limitations of macOS

macOS's Lock Screen is not customisable.

### Third Party Tools

Third party tools, such as [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager), can be used to customise your Mac's energy saving settings and schedule.

Disclaimer: I work on Power Manager, so feel free to ask technical questions about how it can be used.

Comment: Thanks. Can it handle a policy such as: stay on while on AC power for 8a-7p, and Sleep after 30m of inactivity  from 7p-8a even if AC power is on??

Comment: Yes. Try the [demo](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/download) and, if you need more control investigate the [event editor](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/features/editor/). If you need support, get in touch via support@dssw.co.uk